# How to get mean of column using groupby() and another condition

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

For the following

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['1'] = 1,2,1,2,1,2
df['2'] = 3,6,5,4,7,8
df['3'] = 1,1,1,2,2,2
```

I want to do

```py
mean(df.groupby().loc[df['1']==df['3'],'2'].mean()
```

which doesn't work. And simply doing this :

```py
a=df.groupby(['1','3'])['2'].mean()
```

gives

```py
OUTPUT: 
1  3
1  1    4
   2    7
2  1    6
   2    6
```

But I only want cases where column 1 and 3 have the same elements:

```py
1  3
1  1    4
2  2    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
a=df[df['1']==df['3']].groupby(['1','3'])['2'].mean()
```